# How to get the property for a parameter field using Reflection

Tags: c#

I'm fairly new to C# and need a little help. I need to get a list of a methods parameters, get the parameters values and then get the custom attributes for the fields getter/setter property.

I am able to get the parameters and the fields values but I have been unable to find a way to get the property and custom attributes. If there is a more efficient or better way please let me know.

```
Object obj = Activator.CreateInstance(type);

MethodInfo methodInfo = obj.GetType().GetMethods()
                   .Where(x=> x.Name == type.Name)
               .OrderBy(x=> x.GetParameters().Length)
               .Last();
ParameterInfo[] paramInfo = methodInfo.GetParameters();

foreach(var param in paramInfo)
{
  FieldInfo fi = obj.GetType().GetField( param.Name,BindingFlags.Instance   
   BindingFlags.NonPublic);

  //Here I'm just displaying the values fi.Name and fi.GetValue(obj) for now.

}
```

This seems to work OK to get the values but I'm not sure if some of parameters might end up having a BackingField so I also have to address that.

The thing I really need is to now get the property for the getter/setter so I can get the custom attribute from them.

Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Since method parameter names have no intrinsic relation to the names of fields/properties on your class, I'm a bit lost as to what you want to do. Also, do you mean you want to get the values supplied to the method, or any default values that the parameters have (e.g. the value `3` for `a` from a method `void Test(int a = 3)`)?

Comment: Hi John, I need to create a form to allow a user to input the parameter values for the method. So I need to display all of the parameters with the default values. I also need to get the custom attributes for the property which contains some custom display attributes that I need to display and describe the parameter correctly.

Comment: So are you talking about _method parameters_ or _properties_? Can you provide an example of the kind of class you intend to run your code against?

Comment: I don't have the internal code of the methods since I am working with an assembly that was not created by me.. The methods have a varied amount of parameters with various different types. Each parameter has a getter setter and that property has the custom attributes that I need.

Comment: _"Each parameter has a getter setter and that property has the custom attributes that I need"_ - this really sounds like you're talking about _properties_ and not _parameters_ (parameters being the arguments accepted by a method).